# How can we understand and create this parameter inside function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to JS language. I have a lot of confusion in variable declaration that is created with functions. It is usual when you create and call as follows:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b
}
```

We know a, b can be called later by values, no doubt in that

```
console.log(sum(1, 2))
```

But I have a doubt in parameters passed in in-built functions and in general. They are:

```
   var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(function (word) { return word.length > 6} );

console.log(result);
```

How this **word** parameter inside anonymous function grasps each element in array? What is the concept behind that?

Not only in this in-built function, this is my Javascript doubt in general. Every time it confuses me. Kindly someone explain me how to create and use this kind of parameters efficiently.

Comment: this is called a callback function.

Comment: `.filter` calls the callback.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @mithun jack: I cannot vouch for why you were down voted. As for this question: the filter function has been implemented this way. When called upon an array, filter iterates over each element and passes that element to a function (callback function) and returns a new array as the result of operation of the function. This link will perhaps make it clearer for you. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-filter/amp/

Comment: @aman_novice I said I asked this question in general. "Not only in this in-built function, this is my Javascript doubt in general". Filter is just example I've taken from Mozilla developer's site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you're confused on how the anonymous / lambda function operates on the indefinite number of parameters.

Lets write our own filter function to see how it works. First, we'll need two things, an array of objects / values, and some way to map these values to either true (should be in the results array) or false (should not be in the results array). Then all we need to do is select the values that evaluated to try and return them.

```
// Define array
var words = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
// Define filter
function hasAnE(word) {
    return word.includes('e');
}
// Examples
hasAnE(words[0]); // false
hasAnE(words[1]); // false
hasAnE(words[2]); // true

// Create an array for our results
filteredWords = [];
// Go through our words array and check for matches
for (var index = 0; index < words.length; index ++) {
    word = words[index];
    // Map each element to true / false
    filterResult = hasAnE(word);
    // If it matches the filter, add it to the results
    if (filterResult) {
        filteredWords.push(word);
    }
}
console.log(filteredWords); // [ 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present' ]
```

Ok, so we can build a this filter functionality ourselves, but how do we get to `words.filter(hasAnE)`? Well the first thing you need to understand is that in JavaScript, you can pass around functions themselves like variables. This means that we can write a function that takes another function as a parameter (the passed function is called a 'callback').

```
function filterWords(wordsArray, filter) {
    filteredWords = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < wordsArray.length; index ++) {
        word = wordsArray[index];
        // Map each element to true / false
        filterResult = filter(word);
        // If it matches the filter, add it to the results
        if (filterResult) {
            filteredWords.push(word);
        }
    }
    return filteredWords;
}
console.log(filterWords(words, hasAnE)); // [ 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present' ]
```

Notice we get the same results as before. JavaScript allows us to not only pass the filter as an input parameter, but also call it seamlessly. But how is it that we can apply the filter directly to the words array itself? This is where prototypes come in handy as it allows me to change the 'base' code for an existing class. For instance, `Array.prototype` gives me access to all the default fields and methods of the Array class (which our words array is a one of). So using our knowledge that functions can be stored as variables, we can do this:

```
function filterWordsPrototype(filter) {
    filteredWords = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < this.length; index ++) {
        word = this[index];
        // Map each element to true / false
        filterResult = filter(word);
        // If it matches the filter, add it to the results
        if (filterResult) {
            filteredWords.push(word);
        }
    }
    return filteredWords;
}
Array.prototype.filterWords = filterWordsPrototype;

console.log(words.filterWords(hasAnE)); // [ 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present' ]
```

No magic here. and our final `words.filterWords(hasAnE)` looks very close the original `words.filter(someFunction)` Notice how I got rid of the array parameter and changed all the references to the array to `this` instead. That is because I set the function as a method of the array itself (and of all arrays), so `this` now refers to the array I'm calling the function on.

Now of course the actual implementation is far more efficient, safe, and verbose than this, but I hope I've answered your question about the what's roughly going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel has pointed out in the comment your function is a callback function (as in don't call use we'll call you later).

Under the hood the array filter function is implemented something like this:

```
Array.prototype.filter = function (callback) {
  const goodValues = []
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (callback(this[i])) { // your callback is used here
      goodValues.push(this[i])
    }
  }
  return goodValues
}
```

The gist of it is that you supply a function (functions are objects too) as a parameter. Then the filter implementation of filter will use your function to determine if it should keep a value or throw it away.

The `Array.prototype` just means that every time you create a new array `[]` it will have the `filter` function. Although strongly discoursed you can add your own functions to array as well. Sometimes I had a `dump` helper to understand the intermediate values if you chain many maps and filters.

Here is a [demo](https://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/zgqKOg)

Comment: Using `const i = 0`, `i++` would throw an error. The `filter` function also performs several more steps than this in actuality which are defined [in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.filter).

Comment: Your right about const, fixed the example. The above isn't meant to be a correct implementation of the spec, but a simple example to help PO understand what goes on.